# May I expect PostgreSQL combines row sources in union all in the same order they are defined in query?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, union

PostgreSQL seems to fail recognising the sorting is performed by constant and and each constant unambiguously defines corresponding row source, and as a result I observe it computes all row sources before "sorting":

```sql
create table t1 as
select generate_series(1, 10) as c1;


explain analyse
select c1
from (select 1, c1 from t1 where c1 = 1
      union all
      select 2, c1 from t1 where c1 = 2
      union all
      select 3, c1 from t1 where c1 = 3
      union all
      select 4, c1 from t1 where c1 = 4
      order by 1
      limit 1) q
```

```
Subquery Scan on q  (cost=169.84..169.85 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.501..0.685 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Limit  (cost=169.84..169.84 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.479..0.622 rows=1 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=169.84..169.97 rows=52 width=8) (actual time=0.458..0.570 rows=1 loops=1)
              Sort Key: (1)
              Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
              ->  Append  (cost=0.00..168.28 rows=52 width=8) (actual time=0.044..0.476 rows=4 loops=1)
                    ->  Seq Scan on t1  (cost=0.00..41.88 rows=13 width=8) (actual time=0.023..0.046 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Filter: (c1 = 1)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 9
                    ->  Seq Scan on t1 t1_1  (cost=0.00..41.88 rows=13 width=8) (actual time=0.016..0.038 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Filter: (c1 = 2)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 9
                    ->  Seq Scan on t1 t1_2  (cost=0.00..41.88 rows=13 width=8) (actual time=0.016..0.038 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Filter: (c1 = 3)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 9
                    ->  Seq Scan on t1 t1_3  (cost=0.00..41.88 rows=13 width=8) (actual time=0.017..0.039 rows=1 loops=1)
                          Filter: (c1 = 4)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 9
```

However, after removing `order by 1` I'm getting exactly what I want to get - `never executed` notices in query plan:

```sql
explain analyse
select c1
from (select 1, c1 from t1 where c1 = 1
      union all
      select 2, c1 from t1 where c1 = 2
      union all
      select 3, c1 from t1 where c1 = 3
      union all
      select 4, c1 from t1 where c1 = 4
      --order by 1
      limit 1) q
```

```
Subquery Scan on q  (cost=0.00..3.25 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.092..0.195 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..3.24 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.069..0.131 rows=1 loops=1)
        ->  Append  (cost=0.00..168.28 rows=52 width=8) (actual time=0.047..0.078 rows=1 loops=1)
              ->  Seq Scan on t1  (cost=0.00..41.88 rows=13 width=8) (actual time=0.026..0.037 rows=1 loops=1)
                    Filter: (c1 = 1)
              ->  Seq Scan on t1 t1_1  (cost=0.00..41.88 rows=13 width=8) (never executed)
                    Filter: (c1 = 2)
              ->  Seq Scan on t1 t1_2  (cost=0.00..41.88 rows=13 width=8) (never executed)
                    Filter: (c1 = 3)
              ->  Seq Scan on t1 t1_3  (cost=0.00..41.88 rows=13 width=8) (never executed)
                    Filter: (c1 = 4)
```

The question is: is it safe to omit `order by` in such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimizer isn't smart enough to figure out that the rows are already sorted. so it sorts again. For that, it needs all rows. Simply omit the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: thanks, what does prevent optimizer from permuting row sources defined in union all?

Comment: That nobody implemented it. I doubt that we would be interested in such a change: it is a very narrow corner case, and it would require extra processing time in the optimizer for every `UNION ALL` query.